# http request does not work for android version 4

Tags: android, http

I run my application with android version 2 and it works ok, but when i run it with version 4 it appears an exception in line `request.setURI(new URI(url));`

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        try {
            request.setURI(new URI(url));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("http\n");
        }
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

i can not understand what is the problem.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace for the exception

Comment: Are you doing this work inside an asynctask?  cuz starting in andorid 4 you cant make network connections on the main thread. [AsyncTask tutorial](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/)

Comment: No. i don't use asynctask

Comment: slayton it doesn't appear exception from try catch so i can not find what is the problem

Comment: What ever the things it should be in logcat. Post your logcat. And check if your URI is ok. And, if that link is accessible from the device you are testing, also see if you have internet permission.

Comment: the URI it's ok. the same code is work fine on android version 2, the problem is the version 4

Comment: The solution is to use  AsyncTask. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. You have to use [SSLSocketFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html)

Put this after setContentView

```
int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

} if (SDK_INT>8){

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

}
```

HttpClient httpclient = getNewHttpClient();

.... // HttpGet request = new HttpGet(); ..

```
public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                    .getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                    .getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));



            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }
```

MySSLSocketFactory.java

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    super(truststore);

    TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };

    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}

}
```

Comment: Why.  He's not using secure sockets.

Comment: @DaleWilson: Doed not matter .If he want to solve this , he has ti used this

Comment: @NiravRanpara How can you be so sure this is what will solve the problem when the OP has not even posted the log output? given the information we have now I can see no reason to assume that this is will solve the issue...Infact I think NetworkOnMainThread is more likely to be the culprit.